# Как hibernate попросить в зависимости от БД сохранять значение?

Tags: postgresql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-jpa

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804069/hibernate-mapping-between-postgresql-enum-and-java-enum

Как сделать, что hibernate работал с enum так, как нужно в зависимости от БД, способ работает с postgres, а вот тесты на H2 валятся, хочется универсальную реализацию.

st.setObject(index, value.toString(),Types.OTHER); вот в этой строке, если БД H2 то к значению добавляется префикс и все ломается из за этого, если TYPE string все работает, но с postgres ломается.

Может где то нужно аннотацию @TypeDef или @Type как по другому переопределить, в общем если какие то способы не костыльные?

Comment: Мапинг покажите. И что это `st`? Это из конвертора, который вы определили? Его тоже покажите. В таком виде как сейчас вопрос непонятен.

Comment: В ссылке полный пример как используется у меня, из-за этого не дублировал части этого кода https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804069/hibernate-mapping-between-postgresql-enum-and-java-enum